# Disable Remember Me in Login Form

Tags: filters, wp-login-form

I need to disable the 'Remember Me' prompt in login screens.

Based on answers here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/306746/29416 (including my own answer from 2018 with code that I had working then) about disabling the "Remember Me" prompt on the WP login form (wp-login.php), I should be able to do this:

```
    add_filter('login_form_defaults', 'my_disable_remember_me');
    function my_disable_remember_me($args) {
        $args['remember']       = "";
        return $args;
    }
```

This is based on looking at wp-login.php (around line 604) where the 'remember' arguments shows the 'Remember Me' prompt. If the value is empty, or false, the HTML starting in line 605 will not be displayed. This is the code in wp-login.php that outputs the "Remember Me' text and checkbox (line 604).

```
  ( $args['remember'] ?
        sprintf(
            '<p class="login-remember"><label><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="%1$s" value="forever"%2$s /> %3$s</label></p>',
            esc_attr( $args['id_remember'] ),
            ( $args['value_remember'] ? ' checked="checked"' : '' ),
            esc_html( $args['label_remember'] )
        ) : ''
    ) .
```

So using that filter 'login_form_defaults' should remove the prompt. But it doesn't. I have tried the other filters (login_form_top, login_form_middle, login_form_footer) to use the same my_disable_remember_me function, to no avail.

So I am confused as to why the login_form_defaults doesn't remove the "Remember Me" checkbox and text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `login_form_defaults` hook does work, but `wp-login.php` **does not** use [`wp_login_form()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_login_form/) *which runs the `login_form_defaults` hook*, and instead the "Remember Me" checkbox is echoed [like this](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.9/src/wp-login.php#L1413), hence it's basically unremovable via PHP or there's no filter to disable (or an argument to bypass) the echo, or empty/modify the markup.

So that means, if `wp_login_form()` was used, then your code would have worked.

But *on the `wp-login.php` page*, you can disable the "Remember Me" via either CSS or JS, or both:

- Use CSS to visually hide the checkbox, e.g. using the [`login_head` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_head/):

  ```php
  add_action( 'login_head', function () {
      echo '<style>.forgetmenot { display: none !important }</style>';
  } );
  ```
- Use JS to completely remove the element, e.g. using the [`login_footer` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_footer/):

  ```php
  add_action( 'login_footer', function () {
      ?>
          <script>
              try {
                  document.querySelector( '.forgetmenot' ).remove();
              } catch ( err ) {}
          </script>
      <?php
  } );
  ```

Or just create a custom login page and send users to that page instead when they attempt to login.

That way, you can manually call `wp_login_form()` and just disable the "Remember Me" as you wish.

Comment: But I see the 'login_form_defaults' filter in general-templates.php about line 540 , which is what login_form() uses. I can't get the filter to accept non-default 'remember' element in the $args used in general-templates.php .

Comment: Are you actually trying to disable the "Remember Me" ***on the `wp-login.php` page*** or somewhere else? If it is the former, then as stated in my answer, `wp-login.php` does not use `wp_login_form()` which runs the `login_form_defaults` hook, so it's normal if your `my_disable_remember_me()` function didn't work (because it never runs on that page).

Comment: I have revised my answer, but please let me know if I have perhaps misunderstood your actual question?

Comment: As for this: "I can't get the filter to accept non-default 'remember' element in the $args", if you look at line 503, it says, `@type bool $remember Whether to display the "rememberme" checkbox in the form`, so `remember` is just a (boolean) flag and therefore, if you were actually trying to use your own checkbox, then you can use the `login_form_middle` filter to add your markup and set the `remember` to `false`. But once again, `wp-login.php` does not use `wp_login_form()` (but yes, the inputs by default are sent to wp-login.php).

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I assumed, without digging deeply, that the wp-login.php was using wp_login_form, which I was changing via the filter. (Why that is - is puzzling.)
Your JS code worked perfectly.  Thanks.